# PIL.Image.paste does not actually paste the image

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

```
        print('Results found in file {}'.format(filename))
        if len(faces) == 0:
            print('But there were no faces in that file!')
        else:
            pil_img = file_dict(filename)['image']
            # Set our drawing context
            contact_sheet = Image.new('RGB', (128*5,((len(faces)//6 + 1)*128)))
            x = 0
            y = 0
            for x,y,w,h in faces:
                img_copy = pil_img.copy()
                cropped = img_copy.crop((x,y,x+w,y+h))
                cropped.thumbnail((128, 128))
                display(cropped)
                contact_sheet.paste(cropped, (x, y))
                if x+128 == contact_sheet.width:
                    x=0
                    y += 128
                else:
                    x += 128
            display(contact_sheet)
```

I am taking a beginner's course on Python programming and I'm stuck at an assignment that requires me to take some processed images and paste them. I'm having trouble with the pasting. I defined a function in the code above to do that. The inputs are correct and I've debugged everything before the line where the pasting actually happens, `cropped` shows up as an image of the correct type and size when I display it, but when I `display(contact_sheet)` the resulting image is completely black as `contact_sheet` originally was and no errors are returned. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing `box=` for `contact_sheet.paste()`:

```
contact_sheet.paste(cropped, box=(x, y))
```

Comment: Isn't it a positional argument? I've done elsewhere with similar code and it works just fine without

Comment: That's strange, the [docs](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/5.1.x/reference/Image.html?highlight=paste#PIL.Image.Image.paste) seem to suggest otherwise.